# Camerax cannot select a high resolution for VideoCapture on external camera

Tags: android-camerax

Using CameraX 1.4.0-alpha03.

Code like this:

```
    val preview = Preview.Builder()
                 .setResolutionSelector(
                      ResolutionSelector.Builder()
                            .setAllowedResolutionMode(PREFER_HIGHER_RESOLUTION_OVER_CAPTURE_RATE)
                      .setAspectRatioStrategy(AspectRatioStrategy.RATIO_16_9_FALLBACK_AUTO_STRATEGY)
                            .setResolutionStrategy(
                                ResolutionStrategy(
                                    Size(1920, 1080),
                                    ResolutionStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_CLOSEST_HIGHER_THEN_LOWER
                                )
                            ).build()
                 )


    val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                            .addCameraFilter(ExternalCameraFilter(camera.id))
                            .build()
    val qualitySelector = QualitySelector.fromOrderedList(
                listOf(Quality.FHD, Quality.HD, Quality.SD),
                FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(
                    Quality.SD
                )
            )
    val recorder = Recorder.Builder().setQualitySelector(qualitySelector).build()
    val videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
    val useCaseGroup =
                UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                    .addUseCase(preview!!)
                    .addUseCase(videoCapture)
                    .setViewPort(view!!.viewPort!!)
                    .build()

    val cameraProvider = provider.get()
    cameraProvider.unbindAll()

    preview?.setSurfaceProvider(view!!.surfaceProvider)
    
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup)
```

ExternalCameraFilter:

```
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun filter(cameraInfos: MutableList<CameraInfo>): MutableList<CameraInfo> {
        return cameraInfos.filter { camInfo ->
            isExternalCamera(camInfo)
        }.filter {
            try {
                Camera2CameraInfo.from(it).cameraId == cameraId
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                false
            }
        }.toMutableList()
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun isExternalCamera(cameraInfo: CameraInfo): Boolean {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            try {
                Camera2CameraInfo.from(cameraInfo).getCameraCharacteristic(
                    CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL
                ) == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                false
            }
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
```

I got a very low resolution: 640x442.
If remove the `videoCapture` use-case, then got correct 1080P.

Some Logs here:

```
19:59:33.261 CapabilitiesByQuality    E  No supported EncoderProfiles
19:59:33.262 VideoConfigUtil          D  No EncoderProfiles present. May rely on fallback defaults to derive VIDEO settings [chosen mime type: video/avc, dynamic range: DynamicRange@2080ac3{encoding=SDR, bitDepth=8}]
19:59:33.262 UseCaseAttachState       D  Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 102
19:59:33.262 VidEncCfgDefaultRslvr    D  Default resolved frame rate: 30fps. [Expected operating range: <UNSPECIFIED>]
19:59:33.262                          D  Resolved VIDEO frame rate: 30fps
19:59:33.262                          D  Using fallback VIDEO bitrate
19:59:33.263 VideoConfigUtil          D  Base Bitrate(14000000bps) * Bit Depth Ratio (8 / 8) * Frame Rate Ratio(30 / 30) * Width Ratio(640 / 1280) * Height Ratio(442 / 720) = 4297222
19:59:33.263 Camera2CameraImpl        D  {Camera@4890b0c[id=102]} Use case androidx.camera.core.streamsharing.StreamSharing-73ab81ad-8aee-43c8-8758-02fc986545c579779905 ACTIVE
19:59:33.263 UseCaseAttachState       D  Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 102
19:59:33.263 VideoConfigUtil          W  Unsupported mime type video/avc or profile level -1. Data space is unspecified.
19:59:33.283 VideoCapabilities        W  Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
19:59:33.295 CCodec                   D  allocate(c2.rk.avc.encoder)
19:59:33.296 Codec2Client             I  Available Codec2 services: "default" "software"
19:59:33.297 CCodec                   I  setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
19:59:33.302                          I  Created component [c2.rk.avc.encoder]
19:59:33.302 CCodecConfig             D  read media type: video/avc
19:59:33.304 ReflectedParamUpdater    D  extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
19:59:33.304                          D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
19:59:33.304                          D  extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
19:59:33.305                          D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
19:59:33.305                          D  extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
19:59:33.305                          D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
19:59:33.305                          D  extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
19:59:33.306                          D  ignored struct field coding.gop.values
19:59:33.306                          D  ignored struct field coding.qp.values
19:59:33.307 CCodecConfig             D  ignoring local param raw.color (0xc2001809) as it is already supported
19:59:33.308                          I  query failed after returning 14 values (BAD_INDEX)
19:59:33.309                          D  c2 config diff is Dict {
                                           c2::u32 algo.bitrate-mode.value = 3
                                           c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
                                           c2::float coded.frame-rate.value = 1
                                           c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 20489
                                           c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 20480
                                           c2::u32 coded.vui.color.matrix = 0
                                           c2::u32 coded.vui.color.primaries = 0
                                           c2::u32 coded.vui.color.range = 0
                                           c2::u32 coded.vui.color.transfer = 0
                                           c2::u32 coding.intra-refresh.mode = 0
                                           c2::float coding.intra-refresh.period = 0
                                           c2::u32 coding.request-sync-frame.value = 0
                                           c2::i64 coding.sync-frame-interval.value = 1000000
                                           Buffer coding.temporal-layering = {
                                             00000000:  10 00 00 00 07 20 01 52  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ..... .R........
                                           }
                                           c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
                                           string input.media-type.value = "video/raw"
                                           string output.media-type.value = "video/avc"
                                           c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 0
                                           c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 0
                                           c2::u32 raw.color.range = 0
                                           c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 0
                                           c2::u32 raw.size.height = 144
                                           c2::u32 raw.size.width = 176
                                         }
19:59:33.309 ColorUtils               W  expected specified color aspects (0:0:0:0)
19:59:33.313 hw-BpHwBinder            I  onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
19:59:33.314 CameraOrientationUtil    D  getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=0, isOppositeFacing=false, result=0
19:59:33.314 VideoCapture             D  camera timebase = UPTIME, processing timebase = UPTIME
19:59:33.314 DeferrableSurface        D  Surface created[total_surfaces=9, used_surfaces=3](androidx.camera.core.processing.SurfaceEdge$SettableSurface@497ae85}
19:59:33.315                          D  Surface created[total_surfaces=10, used_surfaces=3](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@129ae01}
19:59:33.316                          D  New surface in use[total_surfaces=10, used_surfaces=4](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@129ae01}
19:59:33.316                          D  use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@129ae01
19:59:33.316 Recorder                 D  Surface is requested in state: CONFIGURING, Current surface: 0
19:59:33.317 CameraOrientationUtil    D  getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=0, isOppositeFacing=false, result=0
19:59:33.317 CapabilitiesByQuality    E  No supported EncoderProfiles
19:59:33.318 Recorder                 D  Using supported quality of ConstantQuality{value=-1, name=NONE, typicalSizes=[]} for surface size 640x442
19:59:33.318                          D  Try to safely release video encoder: null
19:59:33.319                          D  Video source has transitioned to state: ACTIVE_NON_STREAMING
```

If list supported resolutions by `CamcorderProfileResolutionQuirk`, got this:
[640x480, 720x480, 720x576, 800x600, 1280x720, 1024x768, 1360x768, 1280x960, 1280x1024, 1920x1080]

I tried to get more info by:

```
                            Recorder.getVideoCapabilities(
                                this.cameraInfo,
                                Recorder.VIDEO_CAPABILITIES_SOURCE_CAMCORDER_PROFILE
                            ).apply {
                                getSupportedQualities(DynamicRange.SDR).apply {
                                    Timber.d("getSupportedQualities ${this}")
                                }
                                Timber.d("supportedDynamicRanges ${supportedDynamicRanges}")
                                Timber.d(
                                    "Profiles FHD: ${
                                        getProfiles(
                                            Quality.FHD,
                                            DynamicRange.SDR
                                        )?.videoProfiles
                                    }"
                                )
                            }
```

And here the result:

```
 D  getSupportedQualities []
 D  supportedDynamicRanges []
 D  Profiles FHD: null
```

It says supported qualities for video is empty, dynamic ranges either, and profile for FHD is null.
Can any one tell me what's wrong here.

Get high resolution with `VideoCapture`.

**Edit:**
Sorry for missing some code here,
There is a `OverlayEffect` left:

```
val overlayEffect = OverlayEffect(
                CameraEffect.PREVIEW or CameraEffect.VIDEO_CAPTURE or CameraEffect.IMAGE_CAPTURE,
                0,
                Handler(),
                {})

...

val useCaseGroup =
                UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                    .addUseCase(preview!!)
                    .addUseCase(videoCapture)
                    .addEffect(overlayEffect)
                    .setViewPort(view!!.viewPort!!)
                    .build()
```

That's the reason why `CameraX` chose a low resolution.
If adding the `OverlayEffect`, low resolution presented.
If not, high resolution is picked.

That might be an issue for CameraX 1.4.0-alpha03.

Finally I build my own camerax module from the newest `androidx` codebase following [onboarding docs](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/docs/onboarding.md), then the issue gone.

**So, close this question.**

Comment: CameraX might thinks FHD is not safe for video encoding. If you post this question to camerax-developers@android.com, the team might be able to tell you how to work around it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help Xi, I edited this post to explain the loss clearly that i missed the most important point.
I use your `OverlayEffect` from this pre alpha version to get a overlay on camera preview.
Well done for you , it's working with the lates code.